# Math chars won’t print although visible in the PDF

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, font-encodings

When compiling the following MWE with LuaLaTeX (up-to-date MacTeX) and then printing the PDF with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC (latest version) the `+` and `=` are not visible on the printed page. However when I use Skip or macOS’ Preview to print everything looks fine. Compiling with XeLaTeX doesn’t show this problem either.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
   \setmathfont{Fira Sans Light}

\begin{document}
a \( a+b=c \)
\end{document}
```

Can someone finde the root of this and even better a solution? I guess it has something to do with font loading or embedding in LuaTeX …

Here are the PDFs created on my system: http://kunden.tobiw.de/missing-chars.zip. A friend of mine could reproduce the behaviour with these PDFs …

Comment: I can't confirm. Anyway, Fira Sans Light is no math font.

Comment: @egreg: With which App did you print? And could you post your file liste somewhere please?

Comment: What happens with + and  = in text mode?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Good question with a strange answer: If I add these chars in text mode they print fine and the ones in math mode print fine too …

Comment: The relevant packages are tuenc.def 2017/04/05, unicode-math.sty 2017/08/02, expl3.sty 2017/09/18, fontspec.sty 2017/09/22. I printed with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, as you told to, with Mac OS X 10.10

Comment: Your pdf prints fine on windows. The fonts are different with luatex: As it sets math mode with Renderer=Basic, there are two versions of fira sans in the pdf. I sent you my pdf per mail.

Comment: The PDF Ulrike send me shows the same problem (characters don’t print). @egreg: Could you pleas e-mail me a PDF created on your system?

Comment: @egreg: The PDF created on your system shows the same error. However I’m using a newer macOS (10.12.6).

Comment: Tried printing from Sierra (10.12.6) with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: the characters show. It seems a problem with your printer driver.

Comment: @egreg: I tried to different printers (Epson Workforce and Samsung Laser-Printer): same result on both, i.e. no math chars.

Comment: A colleague could reproduce my problem on macOS 10.13 with an Epson printer (non-PostScript). Maybe it is a Mac bug introduced in 10.11 or 10.12

Comment: On a side note, Fira Sans doesn’t have full Unicode math coverage, although this shouldn’t be an issue for characters in ASCII. Not an answer to your problem, but you might consider loading the math font with the `range=` option.

Comment: Thanks, I know. I use the option in my doc. I just omitted it for the MWE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because itis a problem with the printer driver

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not a right answer, but I obtain a correct results.

I use Acrobat Reader DC (17.012.20098) and the result is as in the figure.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have no errors, warnings, or any kind of messages in log.

Comment: I have see the result in Acrobat. Tomorrow I'll print it and tell you.

Comment: Acrobat shows the characters but they get lost somewhere on the way to the physical paper

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment.  You can just link to the uploaded screenshot in a comment.